# Two parallel vectors and triple scalar product explanation

Tags: vectors

I don't really know where to start and how to get working that supports the explanation.

Given that $\textbf{u}$ is parallel to $\textbf{v}$, explain why $\textbf{u}\cdot(\textbf{v} \times \textbf{w}) = (\textbf{u} \times \textbf{v})\cdot\textbf{w} = \textbf{0}$.

Comment: Well, what’s the cross product of parallel vectors equal to?

Comment: Well I guess its 0. But I still don't get the u.(v x w) part.

Comment: The first equivalence is a characteristic of the triple scalar product, regardless of the vectors used; this can be seen by writing out the formula of both the triple and dot product explicitly. The second, as has been mentioned, relies on the definiton of a cross product, and moreover on the crossproduct between two parallel vectors.

Comment: So umm could you go into detail about how it works out?

Comment: The cross product $\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}$ gives a vector $\mathbf{z}$ perpendicular to both $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$. Therefore if $\mathbf{u}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{v}$ then it will be perpendicular to $\mathbf{z}$. Thus the triple product is zero. Picture the vectors in your head or draw them and you will see this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The triple product is invariant to a cyclic permutation of its arguments, hence

$$u\cdot(v\times w)=v\cdot(w\times u)=w\cdot(u\times v)=0.$$